# Can't scrape all the company names from a webpage

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm trying to parse all the company names from this ***[webpage](https://www.ycombinator.com/companies/)***. There are around `2431` companies in there. However, the way I've tried below can fetches me `1000` results.

This is what I can see about the number of results in response while going through dev tools:

```
hitsPerPage: 1000
index: "YCCompany_production"
nbHits: 2431      <------------------------       
nbPages: 1
page: 0
```

> How can I get the rest of the results using requests?

I've tried so far:

```
import requests

url = 'https://45bwzj1sgc-dsn.algolia.net/1/indexes/*/queries?'

params = {
    'x-algolia-agent': 'Algolia for JavaScript (3.35.1); Browser; JS Helper (3.1.0)',
    'x-algolia-application-id': '45BWZJ1SGC',
    'x-algolia-api-key': 'NDYzYmNmMTRjYzU4MDE0ZWY0MTVmMTNiYzcwYzMyODFlMjQxMWI5YmZkMjEwMDAxMzE0OTZhZGZkNDNkYWZjMHJlc3RyaWN0SW5kaWNlcz0lNUIlMjJZQ0NvbXBhbnlfcHJvZHVjdGlvbiUyMiU1RCZ0YWdGaWx0ZXJzPSU1QiUyMiUyMiU1RCZhbmFseXRpY3NUYWdzPSU1QiUyMnljZGMlMjIlNUQ='
}
payload = {"requests":[{"indexName":"YCCompany_production","params":"hitsPerPage=1000&query=&page=0&facets=%5B%22top100%22%2C%22isHiring%22%2C%22nonprofit%22%2C%22batch%22%2C%22industries%22%2C%22subindustry%22%2C%22status%22%2C%22regions%22%5D&tagFilters="}]}

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36'
    r = s.post(url,params=params,json=payload)
    print(len(r.json()['results'][0]['hits']))
```

Comment: Extract total count then loop until reached issuing requests whilst altering the page param value. The pagination limit appears to be 1000 with override being server side setting. Don't know what limits occur with [offset and length](https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/building-search-ui/ui-and-ux-patterns/pagination/js/#hit-limit).

Comment: many AP's )if not most) limit the amount of entries returned by one request. In these cases you have to use offsets and perform multiple requests

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As a workaround you can simulate search using alphabet as a search pattern. Using code below you will get all 2431 companies as dictionary with ID as a key and full company data dictionary as a value.

```
import requests
import string

params = {
    'x-algolia-agent': 'Algolia for JavaScript (3.35.1); Browser; JS Helper (3.1.0)',
    'x-algolia-application-id': '45BWZJ1SGC',
    'x-algolia-api-key': 'NDYzYmNmMTRjYzU4MDE0ZWY0MTVmMTNiYzcwYzMyODFlMjQxMWI5YmZkMjEwMDAxMzE0OTZhZGZkNDNkYWZjMHJl'
                         'c3RyaWN0SW5kaWNlcz0lNUIlMjJZQ0NvbXBhbnlfcHJvZHVjdGlvbiUyMiU1RCZ0YWdGaWx0ZXJzPSU1QiUyMiUy'
                         'MiU1RCZhbmFseXRpY3NUYWdzPSU1QiUyMnljZGMlMjIlNUQ='
}

url = 'https://45bwzj1sgc-dsn.algolia.net/1/indexes/*/queries'
result = dict()
for letter in string.ascii_lowercase:
    print(letter)

    payload = {
        "requests": [{
            "indexName": "YCCompany_production",
            "params": "hitsPerPage=1000&query=" + letter + "&page=0&facets=%5B%22top100%22%2C%22isHiring%22%2C%22nonprofit%22%2C%22batch%22%2C%22industries%22%2C%22subindustry%22%2C%22status%22%2C%22regions%22%5D&tagFilters="
        }]
    }

    r = requests.post(url, params=params, json=payload)
    result.update({h['id']: h for h in r.json()['results'][0]['hits']})

print(len(result))
```

Comment: This was an ingenious workaround for the OP's problem.  Definitely worth an upvote in my book, because you taught me something.

Comment: It works! Just have to update Algolia Api key and Algolia agent

Answer (score 8):

**UPDATE 01-04-2021**

After reviewing the "fine print" in the Algolia API [documentation](https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/building-search-ui/ui-and-ux-patterns/pagination/js/#pagination-limitations), I discovered that the *paginationLimitedTo* parameter CANNOT BE USED in a query. This parameter can only be used during *indexing by the data's owner.*

It seems that you can use the query and offset this way:

```
payload = {"requests":[{"indexName":"YCCompany_production",
                        "params": "query=&offset=1000&length=500&facets=%5B%22top100%22%2C%22isHiring%22%2C%22nonprofit"
                                 "%22%2C%22batch%22%2C%22industries%22%2C%22subindustry%22%2C%22status%22%2C%22regions%22%5D&tagFilters="}]}
```

***Unfortunately, the paginationLimitedTo index set by the customer will not let you retrieve more than 1000 records via the API.***

```
"hits": [],
    "nbHits": 2432,
    "offset": 1000,
    "length": 500,
    "message": "you can only fetch the 1000 hits for this query. You can extend the number of hits returned via the paginationLimitedTo index parameter or use the browse method. You can read our FAQ for more details about browsing: https://www.algolia.com/doc/faq/index-configuration/how-can-i-retrieve-all-the-records-in-my-index",
```

**The browsing bypass method mentioned requires an *ApplicationID* and the *AdminAPIKey***

---

**ORIGINAL POST**

Based on the Algolia API [documentation](https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/building-search-ui/ui-and-ux-patterns/pagination/js/#pagination-limitations) there is a query hit limit of 1000.

The documentation lists several ways to override or bypass this limit.

Part of the API is *[paginationLimitedTo](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/api-parameters/paginationLimitedTo/?client=python)*, which by default is set to 1000 for performance and "scraping protection."

The syntax is:

```
'paginationLimitedTo': number_of_records
```

Another [method](https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/building-search-ui/ui-and-ux-patterns/pagination/js/) mentioned in the documentation is setting the parameters *offset* and *length.*

**offset** lets you specify the starting hit (or record)

**length** sets the number of records returned

You could use these parameters to walk the records, thus potentially not impacting your scraping performance.

For instance you could scrape in blocks of 500.

- records 1-500 (offset=0 and length=500)
- records 501-1001 (offset=500 and length=500)
- records 1002-1502 (offset=1001 and length=500)
- etc...

or

- records 1-500 (offset=0 and length=500)
- records 500-1000 (offset=499 and length=500)
- records 1000-1500 (offset=999 and length=500)
- etc...

The latter one would produces a few duplicates, which could be easily removed when adding them to your in-memory storage (list, dictionary, dataframe).

```
----------------------------------------
My system information
----------------------------------------
Platform:    macOS
Python:      3.8.0
Requests:    2.25.1
----------------------------------------
```

Comment: What is required to use to bypass the limit is clear but where to use them is still vague. If I want to use `'paginationLimitedTo': number_of_records`, I can't understand where to put them, meaning within params or payload or somewhere else?

Comment: @MITHU I updated my answer with additional information.

Answer (score 2):

Try an explicit `limit` value in the payload to override the API default.  For instance, insert `limit=2500` into your request string.

Comment: Inserting any key, as in `limit=2500` within payload leads to `Unknown parameter` error in response. I think I failed to follow what you suggested. Thanks.

Comment: You don't insert it as a key; it's a keyword argument in the "params" value.
What does the API documentation tell you about setting that limit?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you need to set the `param` like this to override defaults. With

```
   index.set_settings

  'paginationLimitedTo': number_of_records
```

Example use for Pyhton.

```
 index.set_settings({'customRanking': ['desc(followers)']})
```

Further Info :- https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/api-methods/set-settings/#examples

Answer (score 2):

There are other way to solve this problem. First you can add **&filters=objectID:SomeIds**.
Algolia allows you to send **1000 different queries in one request**.
This body will return you two objects:
`{"requests":[{"indexName":"YCCompany_production","params":"hitsPerPage=1000&query&filters=objectID:271"}, {"indexName":"YCCompany_production","params":"hitsPerPage=1000&query&filters=objectID:5"}]}`
You can check objectID values. Where are some range from 1-30000. Just send random objectIDs from 1-30000 and with only 30 request you will get all 3602 companies.

Here you have my java code:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Start scraping content...>> " + new Timestamp(new Date().getTime()));
        Set<Integer> allIds = new HashSet<>();
        URL target = new URL("https://45bwzj1sgc-dsn.algolia.net/1/indexes/*/queries?x-algolia-agent=Algolia%20for%20JavaScript%20(3.35.1)%3B%20Browser%3B%20JS%20Helper%20(3.7.0)&x-algolia-application-id=45BWZJ1SGC&x-algolia-api-key=Zjk5ZmFjMzg2NmQxNTA0NGM5OGNiNWY4MzQ0NDUyNTg0MDZjMzdmMWY1NTU2YzZkZGVmYjg1ZGZjMGJlYjhkN3Jlc3RyaWN0SW5kaWNlcz1ZQ0NvbXBhbnlfcHJvZHVjdGlvbiZ0YWdGaWx0ZXJzPSU1QiUyMnljZGNfcHVibGljJTIyJTVEJmFuYWx5dGljc1RhZ3M9JTVCJTIyeWNkYyUyMiU1RA%3D%3D");
        String requestBody = "{\"requests\":[{\"indexName\":\"YCCompany_production\",\"params\":\"hitsPerPage=1000&query&filters=objectID:24638\"}]}";
        int index = 1;
        List<String> results = new ArrayList<>();
        String bodyIndex = "{\"indexName\":\"YCCompany_production\",\"params\":\"hitsPerPage=1000&query&filters=objectID:%d\"}";
        for (int i = 1; i <= 30; i++) {
            StringBuilder body = new StringBuilder("{\"requests\":[");
            for (int j = 1; j <= 1000; j++) {
                body.append(String.format(bodyIndex, index));
                body.append(",");
                index++;
            }
            body = new StringBuilder(body.substring(0, body.length() - 1));
            body.append("]}");
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) target.openConnection();
            con.setDoOutput(true);
            con.setRequestMethod(HttpMethod.POST.name());
            con.setRequestProperty(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, APPLICATION_JSON);
            OutputStream os = con.getOutputStream();
            os.write(body.toString().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
            os.close();
            con.connect();
            String response = new String(con.getInputStream().readAllBytes(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            results.add(response);
        }
        results.forEach(result -> {
            JsonArray array = JsonParser.parseString(result).getAsJsonObject().get("results").getAsJsonArray();
            array.forEach(data -> {
                if (((JsonObject) data).get("nbHits").getAsInt() == 0) {
                    return;
                } else {
                    allIds.add(((JsonObject) data).get("hits").getAsJsonArray().get(0).getAsJsonObject().get("id").getAsInt());
                }
            });
        });
        System.out.println("Total scraped ids " + allIds.size());
        System.out.println("Finish scraping content...>>>> " + new Timestamp(new Date().getTime()));
    }
```